# Using \big( causes extra space around minus sign

Tags: math-mode, spacing

If I write `\big( -1 \big)`, then I get largish spaces around the minus sign. It's as if TeX is treating the opening parenthesis as an operand, so I get the same spacing that I would get in `a - b`. Regular `(-1)` works fine, so it seems to be the "big" qualifier that's causing the trouble.

Is this the expected behavior? Is there some workaround that will give me the correct spacing?

Comment: Did you try `\big({-1}\big)`?

Comment: I did now. It works, but I prefer David's approach below.

Comment: Understandable, it is correct :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The markup should be `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` (almost) never use `\big`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\big(-1\big)$

$\bigl(-1\bigr)$

\end{document}
```

Note that `\bigl` preserves the `mathopen` at the start of the term which affects the outer spacing, not just the inner spacing with the following `binop`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\log(-1)$

$\log{(}{-}1{)}$

$\big(-1\big)x$

$\log\big({-}1\big)x$

$\log\bigl(-1\bigr)x$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion of using {-} also worked, but I like the \bigl-\bigr approach better. I assume this also applies to \Big.

Comment: `{-}` locally just changes the interpretation of - but for all such size commands) the l-r forms also preserve the outer spacing as you have a math open and math close at each end of the term as if you had use `(` and `)` `\big(` like `{(}` is a mathord.

Comment: @bubba I added some more examples